# How to copy and paste of image as Picture-In-Picture in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread('C:\Users\SHUSHMA-PC\Desktop\sample\dumb.jpeg',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)


img[100,100]=[255,255,255]
px=img[100,100]


img[500:550,500:550]=[0,0,0]


dumb_face= img[37:111,108:195]
img[0:74,0:87]=dumb_face

imS = cv2.resize(img, (250, 250))
cv2.imshow("output", imS)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

There is no error, it is just that the image is not copying and appears as normal output

[image: this is the output, it is supposed to copy]

Actually, I want to copy the entire image and paste it on the image itself(smaller one). Like image on a image.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please, Explain your question with details.

Comment: how to copy and paste region of image

Comment: Probably your coordinates are wrong. It copied white portion over the white portion. Add your original image and expected output.

Comment: @Nagaraj you have to update your question above to specific what you are intend to do. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are trying to crop the image and save the cropped portion as a new image. Below is the sample code to do that.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r'.\dump.png', 1)  # '1' read as color image
h,w = img.shape[:2]
print 'image height and width = %d x %d' % (h, w)  # 318 * 348 pixels

img = img[50:250,50:280]  # crop image at [h1:h2, w1:w2]
cv2.imwrite(r'.\dump_resized.png',img)
```

Here is cropped and saved image.

[image]

This is what you intended to do?

**UPDATE:**

To resize the image and put it as a picuture-in-picture one. You may resize the image first, by 1/10 for instance.

```
resized_image = cv2.resize(img, (h/8, w/8))
h1, w1 = resized_image.shape[:2]
```

Then put the resized one into the original image.

```
#set top left position of the resized image
pip_h = 10
pip_w = 10
img[pip_h:pip_h+h1,pip_w:pip_w+w1] = resized_image  # make it PIP
cv2.imwrite(r'.\dump_pip.png',img)
```

Here is the resulted PIP image.

[image]

Comment: NO. I want to copy the entire image and paste it on the image itself(smaller one). Like image on a image

Comment: @Nagaraj Updated my answer to create a PIP image.

Comment: @Nagaraj Any feedback? Please read this ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).